# Post data to Web Api 2 using HttpClient with Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I working on a `ASP.Net MVC 5` project which recently required to use `Web API` to send some data via `POST` to another server.

It's more like a middle `API` which get some data via `POST` and send it to another server.
This `API` require Authentication with `username` and `password`.

The default Authentication in this project is `ASP.Net Identity 2`.

Now my problem is that the authentication I am passing with `HttpClient` does not work and return `status code 200` and login path.

Here is my API controller:

```
public class SendController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [Route("~/api/send/data")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostData(Product data)
    {
        return Ok("done.");
    }
}
```

And the code i am using:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2494/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "kamal", "123456"))));

            // HTTP GET
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/send");

            // HTTP POST
            var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/send/data", gizmo);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // 
            }
        }
```

This is the response message:

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcd29ya1xfXFNtc0FwaVxTbXNBcGkuV2ViXGFjY291bnRcbG9naW4=?=
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 03:04:32 GMT
  Set-Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=D0tzqAqeERwp2EPr9V0_MYGn0syYsoBeBTS6C28sjPVo436KO837RC_iXZQstD3bqrH5EGKry7gHCFoqvg8ZNpDVDgA1; path=/; HttpOnly
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 2700
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}
```

And the request message:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:2494/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fsend%2Fdata', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[SmsApi.Web.Models.Product, SmsApi.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Basic a2FtYWw6MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDA=
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 50
}}
```

Is there some configuration i need to set in my project?

Also there is something makes me confused, if i remove `Authorize` attribute, the post request will work but it's also need to send a get request. i mean if i comment the get request, the post request will return `Methos Not Allow`. Why?

Comment: RequestURI is the login page ? Why do you request the login page via HttpClient? The login action by default doesn't have an Authorize attribute, it needs to be publicly available.

Comment: It is publicly available. and I am not requesting the login page. I thing it's the `Authorize` attribute in Api Controller the request login page.

Comment: Ok, it does a redirect to the login page. Are using CORS, I mean is the web api on another domain/server? Can we see the web api authentication setup?

Comment: Not yet. I am testing it inside the same project.

Comment: How did u implement the authentication in your web api...AuthFilter,MiddleWare?

Comment: I didn't. but after more searching, I have come across [this](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/BasicAuthentication/ReadMe.txt) link and it's work for me.